# CDH5.4 - HADOOP_HOME

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I want to ask, what is the HADOOP_HOME path for CDH 5.4?

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.0-1.cdh5.4.0.p0.27/lib/hadoop
```

Comment: `/opt/cloudera/parcels/` not existe in my version it existe `/opt/cloudera/parcel-repo` but is empty

Comment: my version is cdh-5.4.2.0

Comment: I use the `hadoop version`, I find the hadoop that `usr/jars/CDH-5.4.0-1.cdh5.4.0.p0.27` is the HADOOP_HOME

Comment: /opt/cloudera/parcels/ is empty in latest versions